# where to put css in Magento

Tags: css, magento, layout

I have a layout.xml file that triggers and runs properly, but my css does not seem to work.

```
...
<my_handle_name>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/mystyles.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
    </reference>
</my_handle_name>
...
```

**EDIT**

I have a folder structure something like this,

magento->skin->frontend->enterprise->myfolder->css->mystyles.css

and it appears that magento is looking in

magento->skin->frontend->default->default->css->mystyles.css

**how can I edit the layout.xml to go to this directory?**

Comment: have you set your theme name in admin configuration?

Comment: @anil yes my skin and default themes are changed to myfolder

Comment: ok then please go to system clear all cache if still not working check you package name

Comment: I have all caching disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your other setting is working perfect then you have to set your package name and your myfolder in back end for default configuration if you don't have any store, i assume you have only one default store

then go to this step in `Admin`

**System -> Configuration -> design** then set your **package name** instead of **default** and also set **your theme name** instead of **default theme**

Below is the [detail link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/general_group) you can get more idea from it

Comment: This appears to be for a custom module; if so OP cannot have the module set custom theme settings, as those belong to the instance owner.

Answer (score 0):

Custom theme assets belong under the `base/default` theme. Based on your layout XML, your custom CSS file belongs in *`skin/frontend/base/default/css/mystyles.css`*.

Convention is to put your file in a namespaced subfolder to prevent potential collisions with end user files.

Comment: even in enterprise edition? regardless of the 'enterprise' folder?

Comment: you are correct, however for enterprise edition the default installation looks first in the enterprise/default theme and i think that the files need to be located there.

Comment: *"for enterprise edition the default installation looks first in the enterprise/default theme"* Not true if the end implementer changes the package from **enterprise**. `base/default` is the only certain fallback regardless of Magento version.